# Error :- Value Cannot be null Parameter Name:ConnectionString in .Net Core for two database connections

Tags: asp.net-core, database-connection, entity-framework-migrations

The ConnectionString error did not come for connecting one database. It works well. But when I add two databaseContext classes and two database connections there comes this error. This is my first time adding two databases for the backend.

Startup.cs

```
            services.AddDbContext<EmployeeDetailContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));

            services.AddDbContext<DepartmentDetailContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DeptConnection")));

            services.AddCors();
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "Server=DILAN-PC\\SQL2016;Database=Emp;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;",
    "DeptConnection": "Server=DILAN-PC\\SQL2016;Database=Dept;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
}
```

EmployeeDetailContext.cs

```
public class EmployeeDetailContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeDetailContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeDetailContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
            public DbSet<Employee> EmployeeDetails { get; set; }


    }
```

DepartmentDetailContext.cs

```
public class DepartmentDetailContext : DbContext
    {

        public DepartmentDetailContext(DbContextOptions<DepartmentDetailContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Department> DepartmentDetails { get; set; }

    }
```

When I tried to Add-Migration, this error comes. Any solution for this? Is it correct to have two DB context classes? Can anyone recommend to me any source how that I can get more knowledge on connecting many databases to the backend in .net Core?

Comment: Did you specify DbContext when you migrated?

Comment: @Yinqiu no how can I do that?

Comment: `add-migration name -context EmployeeDetailContext`,`update-database -context EmployeeDetailContext`

Comment: I did now, but it also shows connectionString value cannot be null

Comment: Please note that `appsettings.json` instead of `appsettings.cs`.

Comment: Ah sorry, typing mistake. I'll correct it.

Comment: You can directly replace `Configuration.GetConnectionString("xxxxx"))` in your code with your connectionstrings.

Comment: @Yinqiu removing configuration works for migration. but when update database it gives this error `Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.`

Comment: @Yinqiu that can help debug a bit but not recommended, we should not hard code the connection string like that, try to fix the issue and keep using the configuration. Really this is strange from the other users' point of view. Something wrong hidden on the side of the OP.

Comment: Hi @KingKing,Yes, errors like op are strange and shouldn't happen, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
 services.AddDbContext<EmployeeDetailContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer("Server=DILAN-PC\\SQL2016;Database=Emp;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"));

 services.AddDbContext<DepartmentDetailContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer("Server=DILAN-PC\\SQL2016;Database=Dept;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"));
```

Then migrate:

```
add-migration name -context EmployeeDetailContext
update-database -context EmployeeDetailContext
```

Comment: it works. Why is it not working when we use a name for connection assigned in appsettings.json under ConnectionStrings

Comment: It’s not very clear, it’s weird, it looks like you still have errors elsewhere, I suggest you to debug, you can try to get the value of ConnectionStrings to see if it exists, and check your project structure.

Comment: okay I will check. Thank you very much for your time here.

Answer (score 0):

### This works successfully now.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "Server=DILAN-PC\\SQL2016;Database=Emp;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;",
    "DeptConnection": "Server=DILAN-PC\\SQL2016;Database=Dept;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  }
}
```

startup.cs

```
            services.AddDbContext<EmployeeDetailContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));

            services.AddDbContext<DepartmentDetailContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DeptConnection")));

            services.AddCors();
```

EmployeeDetailContext.cs

```
public class EmployeeDetailContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeDetailContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeDetailContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
            public DbSet<Employee> EmployeeDetails { get; set; }


    }
```

DepartmentDetailContext

```
public class DepartmentDetailContext : DbContext
    {

        public DepartmentDetailContext(DbContextOptions<DepartmentDetailContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Department> DepartmentDetails { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Hi @KamalkaFernando,Is there any difference between the code here and the previous one?

Comment: @Yinqiu both are same.